# Federated Authentication in Multi sites

Tags: federated-authentication

I am using `Sitecore 9.1`, I have `multi-sites` using different hostnames.

can I share user context between sites after successful authentication from one site, instead of authenticating from each site separately?

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon the provider you use, you can easily enter values for the sites (the list of sites where the provider(s) will work), `identityProviders` (the list of providers), and externalUserBuilder child nodes.
This config will be your custom file if you are using some other provider and if you are using this for Owin OOTB, you can override Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.config under app_config/Sitecore/Owin.Authentication

In the `mapEntry` within the `identityProvidersPerSites`, you can define multiple `sites` for which you want to enable the authentication -

```
<mapEntry name ="all" type="Sitecore.FederatedAuthentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.FederatedAuthentication">
    <sites hint="list">
        <site>shell</site>
        <site>admin</site>
        <site>website</site>
        <site>xyz</site>
    </sites>
    <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">mapEntry
        <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='AzureAd']" />
        <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='IdentityServer']" />
    </identityProviders>
    <externalUserBuilder type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultExternalUserBuilder, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
         <param desc="isPersistentUser">true</param>
    </externalUserBuilder>
</mapEntry>
```

With this configuration, a virtual user would be created in the Sitecore instance for the authenticated user but this user might not have permission to access Sitecore client application. you need to provide proper rights to access Sitecore client.
For more read the configure an identity provider section here - https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-management/en/configure-federated-authentication.html

Comment: Which config file is being modified here?

Comment: most probably a patch file to override Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.config under app_config/Sitecore/Owin.Authentication

Comment: "most probably"?  You don't know?

Comment: its depends on the developer, I prefer to create a patch and few directly updates the config :)

Comment: You're missing my point. There is no reference in your answer as to what files are being patched. Nor is your config complete enough (full path structure) to be useful on it's own.

Comment: Thanks Mark! Updating the answer.

Comment: Thanks Mahendra for your answer, the above configuration is working correctly if i have subsites under the same host name but it is not working correctly with sites with different hostnames

Comment: I don't think we have any relation of hostnames here, sites we are passing here are site names, which we usually define in sitedefinition config file.